# is it possible to run Dot Net 6 WinForms App on Linux

Tags: c#, winforms, ubuntu, .net-6.0

I have been developing Desktop WinForms Apps in C# for windows over years, especially which have Serial Port Connection for machines and PLC Systems.

Now I have to develop app that works on Linux.
As per my searches I could know that .net 6 is a Cross platform that can work on any any operating system that's having .net6 runtime SDK.

So my question is, if I Develop my app on windows and when it's completely finished, will I be able to deploy it to work on Ubuntu for the final user without any operational problems especially that I will have to use the Serial Port class in my App?

Thank you

Comment: there are still differences that are subtle and not widely discussed (I had issue with TCP KeepAlive setting which was not available in Linux - had to work around). And COM is as tricky as it gets. if you are as good in COM port programming as you claim you would know that whatever strangers on the internet tell you - the only way to know for sure is to run it yourself. and that would answer only for that particular ubuntu version/COM config/.NET build number etc..

Comment: Windows Forms is not and will not be supported on Linux. You'll want to look at a cross platform UI framework for .NET such as MAUI.

Comment: @Luke, and MAUI does not support Linux for some reason oficially, that's why separate [fork](https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/maui-linux "https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/maui-linux") was created

Comment: Thank you
Is it the same if it I make my app in WPF?

Comment: WPF isn't supported either, the closest migration path is Avalonia but you can't just take a WPF project and expect it to run

Comment: You don't have many options to choose from, https://halfblood.pro/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea

Answer (score 0):

As long as you make a console app and use net6.0 this should work. As said in the comments there currently no gui components that work on linux.